# Align div below as the same as above by CSS/JS to create dynamic tooltip

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Is that possible to auto align the box position below (`box-2` and `box-3`) position as the same as above (`box-1`)?

Note: I am trying to add a dynamic tooltip to various div using react.

```
    <div class="box-1"></div>
    <div class="box-2"></div>
    <div class="box-3"></div>
```

Comment: hello. please give more explanations